# Compilation error in angular success method for ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an angular app and I am trying to call a function on success of an ajax call.

Compiler error on lines 3-6 in the following code and I have no idea why, please explain where I have gone wrong.

```
   $http.get(ROOT_API+"webapi/public/events/" + $scope.appId + "/eventTypes").success(
     function(data){
         var sports = [];
         data.forEach(sport -> {
           sports.push({"name":sport})
         });
         $scope.sports = sports;
     }
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a lot of Java, so I didn't use a fat arrow function I used -> instead which was causing odd compilation errors.